# use **kwargs to creat a dictionary-ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, valueerror

I use the following code to create a dictionary, using the content which is read by line.

```
with open(file='ipc_reference.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines[:]:
        line = line.replace('\n', '')
        print(line)
        line_dic = dict(line)
```

the content in ipc_reference.txt is like this:
[image: the file's content]

e.g.

```
农业 = ['A01C1','C12N15/90']
林业 = ['A01C1','A01H1']
```

but it throw an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/projects/ipc_industry/reference_and_count.py", line 10, in <module>
     line_dic = dict(line)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

So I try to directly use the content of the variable "line" like this(because the content in parentheses is too long, I just display two here. Actually, I run the long version in Pycharm.):

```
D3 = dict(农业 = ['A01C1','C12N15/90'],林业 = ['A01C1','A01H1'])
print(D3)
```

Then it's correct! The result of execution is :

```
{'农业': ['A01C1', 'C12N15/90'], '林业': ['A01C1', 'A01H1']}
```

So why did ValueError:dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required occur? How to resolve the problem?

System: Windows 10

Version:Python 3.6

Editor: Pycharm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contents of your file are not treated as Python source code would be, but as a string.  The `dict` constructor, when given an iterable that isn't a mapping, will treat it as an iterable of `(key, value)` pairs.  Strings are iterated character by character, but the `dict` constructor can't unpack the individual characters into `key, value` pairs, so it fails.

What we should do is split each line on the `=`, evaluate the right side as a list literal, and then update our running dictionary:

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open(file='ipc_reference.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    d = {}
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.split(" = ", 1)  # This assumes the key cannot contain ' = ' 
        value = literal_eval(value)
        d[key] = value
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It solved my problem perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

It's because `line` is a **`str`**. One way to go around this is to use `exec()`. Which executes strings as Python commands.

```
formatted = f'D3 = dict({line})'
exec(formatted)

print(D3)
```

Output where `line` = `'农业 = ['A01C1','C12N15/90']'`:

```
{'农业': ['A01C1', 'C12N15/90']}
```

Comment: I also tried it but it only can solve my problem partly.  I get another error - SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier. Some person say that  it's because there are some character in the middle of a variable name, function, etc. that's not a letter, number, or underscore.But I cannot find them, so I adopted the other's answer. Anyway, thank you!